# Plotting date labels with mpld3

Tags: python, datetime, mpld3

I need help with this. 
The plot is fine but when I'm hovering over the points I get the S&P price as y (which is right) but instead of the date as x I get a timestamp.
Is there anyone able to fix it? Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3
from mpld3 import plugins
import pandas.io.data as pdweb
import datetime
mpld3.enable_notebook()
%matplotlib inline


price = pdweb.get_data_yahoo("^GSPC",start = datetime.datetime(2014,1,1),end=datetime.datetime(2016,6,30))['Adj Close']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax.plot(price.index, price, lw=1)
points = ax.scatter(price.index, price, alpha=0.1)
plugins.connect(fig, plugins.LineLabelTooltip(points))
```

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't the best method but it works :

```
series = ax.plot(price)
date_axis = [pd.to_datetime(str(date)).strftime('%Y.%m.%d') for date in series[0].get_data()[0]]
labels = [(date, " {0}".format(val)) for date, val in zip(date_axis,   series[0].get_data()[1])]
```

So in steps to make it a little clearer than the mess above :

1) plot price series

```
series = ax.plot(price)
```

2) Taking each date in numpy.ndArray of datatime64 (the x axis of the series) and making it a string.

```
string_dates = [str(date) for date in series[0].get_data()[0]]
```

3) Then converting the strings to pandas datetime.

```
dates = [pd_to_datetime(date) for date in string_dates]
```

4) Then using strftime() to format each date string and saving it into date_axis

```
date_axis = [date.strftime('%Y.%m.%d') for date in dates]
```

Like I said, this is almost certainly not an efficient way of doing this, but it worked for me as a temporary solution after trying to figure it out for awhile. Found this elsewhere on SO, don't have the link to hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I get this error..any idea how to solve it? thanks again

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'